# How to return the sum of one column by sorting through another column in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For example, below is my data frame `df`. I want to return the sum of `QuarterSales` for each Brand as another dataframe.

```
0        Quarter       Brand          QuarterSales
1           1           Nike              50
2           1           Puma              50
3           2           Nike              60
4           2           Puma              45
```

This is my desired output below:

```
0      Brand       QuarterSales
1       Nike          110
2       Puma           95
```

Comment: `df.groupby("Brand")["QuarterSales"].sum()` ?

Comment: you can pass `as_index=False` to the groupby to get a returned dataframe i.e `df.groupby("Brand",as_index=False)["QuarterSales"].sum()`